# Handling JMSMessage(Object Message) in IBM WebSphere Message broker

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I am using IBM WebSphere Message Broker to process a JMS message. My message contains a Java object wrapped inside the JMSMessage (Object Message). I couldn't use any other parser other than BLOB in input node. How can I fetch the object from the BLOB domain in JMS Message using JavaCoumpute node? Please help me resolving this.

Comment: Did you try to access it through "InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB"?

Comment: I would do this differently... Is your object very big? If not, I suggest you use a message of type TextMessage where you can use JAXB to marshall or unmarshall your objects